reading and playing packets to a server using a pcap file
I'm trying to solve perform the following tasks:

Capture the packets that are going to the server using wireshark
Write a client program to use the wireshark pcap file and play the same towards the server
Dump the request /response into another file.

I know how to capture packets using the pcap file, but I'm having issues in connecting with a server. Can anyone provide a full solution using Pythons Scapy and pyshark library?
This is my code, where 'current.pcap' is the pcap file I'll be using. I seem to be having issues with connecting to a server.
import pyshark
from scapy.all import *
import time

def read_pcap(file):
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture(file)
    packets = []
    for packet in cap:
        packets.append(packet)
    return packets

def replay_packets(packets, server_ip, server_port):
    responses = []
    for packet in packets:
        try:
            # Convert PyShark packet to Scapy packet
            scapy_pkt = IP(raw(packet.get_raw_packet()))

            # Change destination IP and port to the server
            scapy_pkt[IP].dst = server_ip
            scapy_pkt[UDP].dport = server_port
            
            # Send packet and capture response
            response = sr1(scapy_pkt, timeout=2)
            responses.append(response)
            
            # Wait a bit between packets to mimic real traffic
            time.sleep(0.1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing packet: {e}")
    return responses

def dump_to_file(requests, responses, file):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for req, resp in zip(requests, responses):
            f.write(f"Request: {req}\nResponse: {resp}\n\n")

def main():
    input_pcap_file = 'current.pcap'
    output_file = 'output.txt'
    server_ip = '123.56.8.0'
    server_port = 80

    packets = read_pcap(input_pcap_file)
    requests = [packet.get_raw_packet() for packet in packets]
    responses = replay_packets(packets, server_ip, server_port)
    dump_to_file(requests, responses, output_file)
    print("Finished processing packets.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


It sounds like you want to use
tcpreplay.
It lets you capture an arbitrary tcpdump / wireshark *.pcap file,
and replay those packets later.
Alternatively you might care to write a program which consumes
a pcap file, makes slight adjustments to it, and writes the
filtered content to another pcap file which can then be replayed.
